# Solr: processing of query with punctuation mark

Tags: solr, punctuation

I have the following field in `schema.xml`:

```
 <field name="content" type="text_snowballstem" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="false" termVectors="true" />
```

Field type definition:

```
  <fieldType name="text_snowballstem" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
        catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1"
        splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1"
        stemEnglishPossessive="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" protected="no_stemming.txt"/>
          <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>        
  </fieldType>
```

Now, let's say Solr indexed 2 records with contents:

- "Select the items that did not match their description:"
- "Description"

For this query

```
content:"description"
```

solr will return 2 records. Which is what we expect. But for query

```
content:"descirption\:"
```

it also returns 2 records. Why colon symbol is ignored here? I expect to receive only 1 record in results.

Appreciate any advice.

---

UPD

I've implemented suggested changes to `WordDelimeterFilterFactory`:

```
 <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
        catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1"
        splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1"
        stemEnglishPossessive="1" preserveOriginal="1" types="nosplit.txt"/>
```

and `nosplit.txt` file:

```
# Don't split numbers at '$', '.' or ':'
: => ALPHA
$ => ALPHA
. => ALPHA
- => ALPHA
```

However Solr analyzer still shows 2 tokens for `content:description:`[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

#### 1st Approach

**WordDelimiterFilterFactory** is producing two token for **description:**

1. description:
2. description

you can check this. Just go to analysis at solr admin screen. Choose your fieldType and paste the data and then you can see the corresponding tokens. 
That's why when you searching for description the description: is also coming in results.
We can control this behaviour that **WDF** won't split on colon.

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
        catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1"
        splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1"
        stemEnglishPossessive="1" preserveOriginal="1" types="nosplit.txt"/>
```

[**nosplit.txt**]

```
# Don't split numbers at '$', '.' or ':'
: => ALPHA
$ => ALPHA
. => ALPHA
```

I have added one more argument **types** which will change the splitting behaviour for **WDF**. After this it will only produce the 1st token not 2nd one. 
P.S :- **types argument is available from 6.5 onwards**. So if you are using older version it will not work.

#### 2nd Approach

You can use the protected argument

> protected: (optional) The pathname of a file that contains a list of
>   protected words that should be passed through without splitting.

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
        catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1"
        splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1"
        stemEnglishPossessive="1" preserveOriginal="1" protected="prot.txt"/>
```

[prot.txt]

```
description:
```

This feature is available in both Solr 5 and 6.

#### 3rd Approach

You can use raw query parser. This query parser search for input test without any text analysis or transformation.

```
{!raw f=content}description\:
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I've tried your approach and updated my question.